# Array addition in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How can add arrays in documents in MongoDB?

e.g.:

```
{"_id":1, "a":[1,2,3,4]}

{"_id":2, "a":[3,4,5,6]}
```

result:

```
{"sum":[4,6,8,10]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to do through [`aggregation`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)

```
> db.collection.aggregate([
          // 1. unwind the array a with this array index
          {$unwind: {path: '$a', includeArrayIndex: 'index'}}, 
          // 2. sum them by their index
          {$group: {
                   _id: '$index', 
                   a: {$sum: '$a'}
          }},
          // 3. sort by array index
          {$sort: {_id: 1}},
          // 4. group them into the sum array
          {$group: {_id: null, sum: {$push: '$a'}}}
   ])
```